# How to execute a python notebook inside another one at google cloud datalab

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I'd like to execute a python notebook I'had created to data pre-processing inside another notebook related with data classification process. So the last notebook depends on the functions and execution provided by the first notebook.

How could I do that at google cloud datalab environment? I do like to reuse the functions and variables used at the pre-processing notebook on the classification notebook.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
myNotebook = <relative path to notebook>

%run $myNotebook
```

or simply

```
%run <relative path to notebook>
```

Note: This does not work if you are running [Datalab on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-gce).